# Had my slideshow working on IE and google chrome, now it displays it but seems to not start it and next buttons don't work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I am new to programming and someone else programmed this slideshow on this page before me. I was adding some changes to the java where i might have deleted or added something to jQuery based image slider second code below. As of now the first image is shown with the arrows but it seems that the slideshow does not begin and the arrows can't move the images. Let me know if you can help Thank you

This i think is the main JS file

```
     /* jQuery based image slider
    /* TMSlider 0.3.2 */

    (function($,undefined){

var _TMS=window._TMS=$.fn._TMS=function(_){
        _=_||{}         
        _=$.extend(clone(_TMS),_TMS.presets[_.preset],_)
        _.init.call(_.me=_.holder=this,_)
        return _.me.data({opt:_})
    }

$.extend(_TMS,{
    etal:'<div></div>',
    items:'.items>li',
    pic:'pic',
    mask:'mask',
    paginationCl:'pagination',
    currCl:'current',
    pauseCl:'paused',
    bannerCl:'banner',
    numStatusCl:'numStatus',
    pagNums:true,
    overflow:'hidden',
    show:0,
    changeEv:'click',
    blocksX:1,
    blocksY:1,
    preset:'simpleFade',
    duration:1000,
    easing:'linear',
    way:'lines',
    anim:'fade',
    pagination:false,
    banners:false,
    waitBannerAnimation:true,
    slideshow:false,
    progressBar:false,
    pauseOnHover:false,
    nextBu:false,
    prevBu:false,
    playBu:false,
    preFu:function(){
        var _=this,
            img=$(new Image())
        _.pic=$(_.etal)
            .addClass(_.pic)
            .css({overflow:_.overflow})
            .appendTo(_.me)
        _.mask=$(_.etal)
            .addClass(_.mask)
            .appendTo(_.pic)

        if(_.me.css('position')=='static')
            _.me.css({position:'relative'})
        if(_.me.css('z-index')=='auto')
            _.me.css({zIndex:1})

        _.me.css({overflow:_.overflow})

        if(_.items)
            _.parseImgFu()
        img
            .appendTo(_.me)
            .load(function(){
                _.pic
                    .css({
                        width:'940px', //_.width=img.width()
                        height:_.height=img.height(),
                        background:'url('+_.itms[_.show]+') 0 0 no-repeat'
                    })
                img.remove()
                _.current=_.buff=_.show
            })
            .attr({src:_.itms[_.n=_.show]})
    },
    sliceFu:function(w,h){
        var _=this,
            w=_.blocksX,
            h=_.blocksY,
            eW=parseInt(_.width/w),
            eH=parseInt(_.height/h),
            etal=$(_.etal),
            fW=_.pic.width()-eW*w,
            fH=_.pic.height()-eH*h,
            x,y,
            matrix=_.matrix=[]

        _.mask
            .css({
                position:'absolute',
                width:'100%',
                height:'auto',
                left:0,
                top:0,
                zIndex:1
            })
            .empty()
            .appendTo(_.pic)

        for(y=0;y<h;y++)
            for(x=0;x<w;x++)
                matrix[y]=matrix[y]?matrix[y]:[],
                matrix[y][x]=$(_.etal).clone()
                    .appendTo(_.mask)
                    .css({
                         left:x*eW,
                         top:y*eH,
                         position:'absolute',
                         width:x==w-1?eW+fW:eW,
                         height:y==h-1?eH+fH:eH,
                         backgroundPosition:'-'+x*eW+'px -'+y*eH+'px',
                         display:'none'
                     })
        if(_.maskC){
            _.maskC.remove()
            delete _.maskC
        }
        _.maskC=_.mask.children()           
    },
    changeFu:function(n){
        var _=this
        if(_.bl)
            return false
        if(n==_.n)
            return false
        _.n=n
        _.next=_.itms[n]
        _.direction=n-_.buff
        if(_.direction==_.itms.length-1)
            _.direction=-1
        if(_.direction==-1*_.itms.length+1)
            _.direction=2
        _.current=_.buff=n

        if(_.numStatus)
            _.numStatusChFu()

        if(_.pagination)
            _.pags
                .removeClass(_.currCl)
                .eq(n)
                    .addClass(_.currCl)

        if(_.banners!==false&&_.banner)
            _.bannerHide(_.banner,_)
        if(_.progressBar)
            clearInterval(_.slShTimer),
            _.progressBar.stop()
        if(_.slideshow&&!_.paused&&_.progressBar)
            _.progressBar.stop().width(0)

        var _fu=function(){
            //if(_.banner)
                //$.when(_.banner).then(function(){_.banner.detach()})
            if(_.preset_!=_.preset)
                _.du=_.duration,
                _.ea=_.easing,
                $.extend(_,_TMS.presets[_.preset]),
                _.duration=_.du,
                _.easing=_.ea,
                _.preset_=_.preset
            _.sliceFu()
            _.maskC.stop().css({backgroundImage:'url('+_.next+')'})
            _.beforeAnimation()
            _.showFu()
        }
        if(_.waitBannerAnimation)
            $.when(_.banner).then(_fu)
        else
            _fu()
    },
    nextFu:function(){
        var _=this,
            n=_.n
        _.changeFu(++n<_.itms.length?n:0)
    },
    prevFu:function(){
        var _=this,
            n=_.n
        _.changeFu(--n>=0?n:_.itms.length-1)
    },
    showFu:function(){
        var _=this,
            way,
            tmp

        way=_.ways[_.way].call(_)           

        if(_.reverseWay)
            way.reverse()
        if(_.dirMirror)
            way=_.dirMirrorFu(way)

        if(_.int)
            clearInterval(_.int)
        _.int=setInterval(function(){
            if(way.length)
                _.anims[_.anim].apply(_,[way.shift(),!way.length])
            else
                clearInterval(_.int)//,
                //$.when(_.maskC).then(function(){_.maskC.remove(),delete _.maskC})
            },_.interval)
        _.bl=true           
    },
    dirMirrorFu:function(way){
        var _=this
        if(_.direction<0)
            void(0)
        return way
    },
    afterShow:function(){
        var _=this
        _.pic.css({backgroundImage:'url('+_.next+')'})
        _.maskC.hide()
        if(_.slideshow&&!_.paused)
            _.startSlShFu(0)
        if(_.banners!==false)
            _.banner=_.banners[_.n]                 
        if(_.banner)
            _.banner.appendTo(_.me),
            _.bannerShow(_.banner,_)
        _.afterAnimation()
        _.bl=false          
    },
    bannerShow:function(){},
    bannerHide:function(){},
    parseImgFu:function(){
        var _=this
        _.itms=[]
        $(_.items+' img',_.me)
            .each(function(i){
                _.itms[i]=$(this).attr('src')
            })
        $(_.items,_.me).hide()
    },
    controlsFu:function(){
        var _=this
        if(_.nextBu)
            $(_.nextBu).bind(_.changeEv,function(){
                _.nextFu()
                return false
            })
        if(_.prevBu)
            $(_.prevBu).bind(_.changeEv,function(){
                _.prevFu()
                return false
            })
    },
    paginationFu:function(){
        var _=this                  
        if(_.pagination===false)
            return false
        if(_.pagination===true)
            _.pags=$('<ul></ul>')                   
        else
            if(typeof _.pagination=='string')
                _.pags=$(_.pagination)
        if(_.pags.parent().length==0)
            _.pags.appendTo(_.me)
        if(_.pags.children().length==0)
            $(_.itms).each(function(n){
                var li=$('<li></li>').data({num:n})
                _.pags.append(li.append('<a href="#"></a>'))
            })
        else
            _.pags.find('li').each(function(n){
                $(this).data({num:n})
            })
        if(_.pagNums)
            _.pags.find('a').each(function(n){
                $(this).text(n+1)
            })
        _.pags.delegate('li>a',_.changeEv,function(){
            _.changeFu($(this).parent().data('num'))
            return false
        })
        _.pags.addClass(_.paginationCl)
        _.pags=$('li',_.pags)
        _.pags.eq(_.n).addClass(_.currCl)
    },
    startSlShFu:function(prog){
        var _=this
        _.paused=false
        _.prog=prog||0
        clearInterval(_.slShTimer)
        _.slShTimer=setInterval(function(){
            if(_.prog<100)
                _.prog++
            else
                _.prog=0,
                clearInterval(_.slShTimer),
                _.nextFu()                      
            if(_.progressBar)
                _.pbchFu()
        },_.slideshow/100)
        if(_.playBu)
            $(_.playBu).removeClass(_.pauseCl)              
    },
    pauseSlShFu:function(){
        var _=this
        _.paused=true
        clearInterval(_.slShTimer)
        if(_.playBu)
            $(_.playBu).addClass(_.pauseCl)
    },
    slideshowFu:function(){
        var _=this              
        if(_.slideshow===false)
            return false

        if(_.playBu)
            $(_.playBu).bind(_.changeEv,function(){
                if(!_.paused)
                    _.pauseSlShFu()
                else
                    _.startSlShFu(_.prog)
                return false
            })
        _.startSlShFu()
    },
    pbchFu:function(){
        var _=this
        if(_.prog==0)
            _.progressBar.stop().width(0)
        else
            _.progressBar
                .stop()
                .animate({width:_.prog+'%'},{easing:'linear',duration:_.slideshow/100})
    },
    progressBarFu:function(){
        var _=this
        if(_.progressBar===false)
            return false
        _.progressBar=$(_.progressBar)
        if(_.progressBar.parent().length==0)
            _.progressBar.appendTo(_.me)
    },
    pauseOnHoverFu:function(){
        var _=this
        if(_.pauseOnHover)
            _.me
                .bind('mouseenter',function(){
                    _.pauseSlShFu()
                })
                .bind('mouseleave',function(){
                    _.startSlShFu(_.prog)
                })
    },
    bannersFu:function(){
        var _=this
        if(_.banners===false)
            return false
        if(_.banners!==true&&typeof _.banners=='string')
            _.bannerShow=_.bannersPresets[_.banners].bannerShow,
            _.bannerHide=_.bannersPresets[_.banners].bannerHide
        _.banners=[]
        $(_.items,_.me).each(function(i){
            var tmp
        _.banners[i]=(tmp=$('.'+_.bannerCl,this)).length?tmp.css({zIndex:999}):false
        })
        _.bannerShow(_.banner=_.banners[_.show].appendTo(_.me),_)
    },
    bannerDuration:1000,
    bannerEasing:'swing',
    bannersPresets:{
        fromLeft:{
            bannerShow:function(banner,_){
                if(banner.css('top')=='auto')
                    banner.css('top',0)
                banner
                    .stop()
                    .css({left:-banner.width()})
                    .animate({
                        left:0
                    },{
                        duration:_.bannerDuration,
                        easing:_.bannerEasing
                    })
            },
            bannerHide:function(banner,_){
                banner
                    .stop()
                    .animate({
                        left:-banner.width()
                    },{
                        duration:_.bannerDuration,
                        easing:_.bannerEasing
                    })
            }
        },
        fromRight:{
            bannerShow:function(banner,_){
                if(banner.css('top')=='auto')
                    banner.css('top',0)
                if(banner.css('left')!='auto')
                    banner.css('left','auto')
                banner
                    .stop()
                    .css({right:-banner.width()})
                    .animate({
                        right:0
                    },{
                        duration:_.bannerDuration,
                        easing:_.bannerEasing
                    })
            },
            bannerHide:function(banner,_){
                banner
                    .stop()
                    .animate({
                        right:-banner.width()
                    },{
                        duration:_.bannerDuration,
                        easing:_.bannerEasing
                    })
            }
        },
        fromBottom:{
            bannerShow:function(banner,_){
                if(banner.css('left')=='auto')
                    banner.css('left',0)
                if(banner.css('top')!='auto')
                    banner.css('top','auto')
                banner
                    .stop()
                    .css({bottom:-banner.height()})
                    .animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },{
                        duration:_.bannerDuration,
                        easing:_.bannerEasing
                    })
            },
            bannerHide:function(banner,_){
                banner
                    .stop()
                    .animate({
                        bottom:-banner.height()
                    })
            }
        },
        fromTop:{
            bannerShow:function(banner,_){
                if(banner.css('left')=='auto')
                    banner.css('left',0)
                banner
                    .stop()
                    .css({top:-banner.height()})
                    .animate({
                        top:0
                    },{
                        duration:_.bannerDuration,
                        easing:_.bannerEasing
                    })
            },
            bannerHide:function(banner,_){
                banner
                    .stop()
                    .animate({
                        top:-banner.height()
                    },{
                        duration:_.bannerDuration,
                        easing:_.bannerEasing
                    })
            }
        },
        fade:{
            bannerShow:function(banner,_){
                if(banner.css('left')=='auto')
                    banner.css('left',0)
                if(banner.css('top')=='auto')
                    banner.css('top',0)
                banner
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn(_.bannerDuration)
                    /*.stop()
                    .css({opacity:0})
                    .animate({opacity:1},{
                        duration:_.bannerDuration,
                        easing:_.bannerEasing
                    },function(){
                        if($.browser.msie&&$.browser.version<9)
                            banner.css({opacity:'none'})
                    })*/
            },
            bannerHide:function(banner,_){
                banner
                    .fadeOut(_.bannerDuration)
                    /*.stop()
                    .animate({opacity:0},{
                        duration:_.bannerDuration,
                        easing:_.bannerEasing
                    })*/
            }
        }
    },
    numStatusChFu:function(){
        var _=this
        _.numSt.html('<span class="curr"></span>/<span class="total"></span>')

        $('.curr',_.numSt).text(_.n+1)
        $('.total',_.numSt).text(_.itms.length)
    },
    numStatusFu:function(){
        var _=this
        if(_.numStatus===false)
            return false
        if(!_.numSt)
            if(_.numStatus===true)
                _.numSt=$(_.etal).addClass(_.numStatusCl)
            else
                _.numSt=$(_.numStatus).addClass(_.numStatusCl)
        if(!_.numSt.parent().length)
            _.numSt.appendTo(_.me)
            .addClass(_.numStatusCl)

        _.numStatusChFu()
    },
    init:function(_){
        _.preFu()
        _.controlsFu()
        _.paginationFu()
        _.slideshowFu()
        _.progressBarFu()
        _.pauseOnHoverFu()
        _.bannersFu()
        _.numStatusFu()
    },
    afterAnimation:function(){},
    beforeAnimation:function(){}
})

          })(jQuery)

          function clone(obj){
     if(!obj||typeof obj!=typeof {})
    return obj
if(obj instanceof Array)
    return [].concat(obj)
var tmp=new obj.constructor(),
    i
for(i in obj)
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
        tmp[i]=clone(obj[i])
 return tmp
     }
     /*cGx6a24gY29kZWQgdGhhdHMgY29kZQ==*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is, but perhaps the code from this page can help you:
http://www.drivehq.com/folder/p9420255/1897762608.aspx

This seems to be the original file. If this works then you could compare the 2 files to find the differences, and if this does not work as well, then you know the problem is not within this file.

Ron.

Comment: looks like it might be in another problem. I have the slideshow sort of working but when i click the button on IE slowly goes to the next page and for some reason on chrome doesn't recognize the # button to be the next image. Is there more files needed to be added.